# sum with conditional defined

Tags: python, odoo

I am carrying out a method which has to be added only when it is in the "Cash" account, but when performing in the way below it does not work for me. Anyone know how to add a conditional and add it.

```
class Account (models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.account'

    name = fields.Char (string = "Name")
    total_account_must = fields.Float (string = "Total account must", compute = "_total_account_must")
    total_account_credit = fields.Float (string = "Total account credit", compute = "_total_account_credit")
    detail_document_ids = fields.One2many (comodel_name = 'project_rc.detail_document', inverse_name = 'account_id', string = 'Document detail',required = True)


    @ api.one
    @ api.depends (detail_document_ids)
    def _total_account_must(self):
        sum = 0
        if self.title == "Cash":
            for detail_document in self.detail_document_ids:
                 sum + = detail_document.total_must
                 self.total_account_must = sum

class Document_Detail (models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.detail_document'

   total_must = fields.Float (string = "Input value")
   total_credit = fields.Float (string = "Output value")
   account_id = fields.Many2one (comodel_name = 'project_rc.account', string = 'Account')
```

Comment: self.title is the "cash" account? can you please explain more what is the exact problem?

Comment: One can create many accounts, either the "cash" account, "bank" and each one has movements, so I want to add all the movements that each account has, so there are two tables that are "Account" and "detail_movement ".

I leave a photo so you can understand better if in words it was not done correctly. https://ibb.co/hWM44Hj

Comment: What do you mean by not working, the method is not called? The computed value is wrong? You get errors?

Comment: When I say it does not work, it does not run and errors appear which is not defined since it is a generic error of the method I try to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But i bit confused in this field called **document_document_ids** You have used **detail_document_ids** in Compute.

Try to give as

```
@ api.one
@ api.depends (detail_document_ids.total_must)
def _total_account_must(self):
    self.total_account_must = sum(line.total_must for line in self.detail_document_ids) if self.title == "Cash" else 0
```

Comment: The code does not work. The field mentioned as document_document_ids is detail_document_ids it was only a translation error but it was already corrected above. Now the code I mention does not work which causes me errors. Is there another way it works?

Comment: I edit: when executing the program it opens it to me but when I enter the window corresponding to "accounts" I get the following error.

AttributeError: 'project_rc.detail_document' object has no attribute 'detail_document_ids'

Answer (score 0):

Give the depends a string.

```
@api.depends('detail_document_ids')
```

Also does the _total_account_credit function exist?

Comment: Hello, if there are both functions but the credit is not executed because first I want to see if one works and then operate the same way the other. Try putting only detail_document_ids but it doesn't work.

Comment: I edit: when executing the program it opens it to me but when I enter the window corresponding to "accounts" I get the following error.

AttributeError: 'project_rc.detail_document' object has no attribute 'detail_document_ids'

Comment: AttributeError: 'project_rc.detail_document' object has no attribute 'detail_document_ids'

Comment: @FranciscoGonzálezMejías

The error you received would indicate that you've put the function in the wrong class (it's trying to access the detail_document_ids on the project_rc.detail_document model, instead of the project_rc.account model)  __


I'm assuming that both total_account_must and total_account_credit fields will depend on detail_document_ids so it would make sense to calculate both at the same time. __ 


Also, if you have a depends on the def _total_account_must definition, you're probably going to want store=True in the total_account_must field definition.

Comment: I think there is an error because the method is placed in the "account" class, which is where the "cash" and "bank" account is registered, so that is where I want to see the sum of each account. I have the code as it is in the initial description of the problem.

Comment: I could already make it work. I just had to put total_must and not detail_document _ids.total_must